# Rotate array element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, rotation

I have array of angles and I wanted to loop each angle and display different direction  of css class in each row table. But, the loop does not display different direction. I tried  this code, but it only show one direction if i call the function  outside the loop and it does not show any direction if i call the function inside the loop.  I am not sure how to connect to each angles and css class element. Example in row one i want element point to 90 degree, in row two 45 degree ....line 6 point to 60 degree

```
    var angle = [90, 45, 170, 180, 270, 60]
    list = ''; 

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
          list += '<tr>'; 
          list +='<td>'+ "<div class='fa fa-angle-double-up'> </div>"
          list +='</tr>'; 
          rotate(angle[i]);  // not show any direction 
      }
     $('#imagetable > tbody').html(list); 


     function rotate (angle){
            $(".fa-angle-double-up").rotate(angle);
        }
     rotate(angle[i]);  // show  direction on the selected angle
```

Comment: The first, I want to see your whole code. The second, id is unique, but you made many same <tr id="list" />

Comment: If for-loop end, there are 6 <tr id="list"> tags.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you call the rotate function before the elements have been added to the DOM. Try adding another loop directly after adding like so:

```
$("#imagetable > tbody").html(list);
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    rotate(angle[i]);
}
```